# Disable the Service Help Page and also .asmx?wsdl definitions

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, asmx

I have created a ASMX web service. Now it shows help page with definition ,.asmx?wsdl definitions etc in the url . So i found a method to hide it [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/2tyf2t8t(v=vs.80).aspx)
It says "Modify the webServices section of Web.config to explicitly remove the Documentation protocol"

```
<webServices>
 <protocols>
   <remove name="Documentation" />
 </protocols>
</webServices>
```

But in my case i dont see any  tag in web.config. So where should i add this? Am i missing anythging?

**EDIT**:

I just added below lines in web.config  and it removed service help page with MyBlank.aspx but still .asmx?wsdl is visible from browser.

```
<webServices>   
<wsdlHelpGenerator href="MyBlank.aspx"></wsdlHelpGenerator>         
</webServices>
```

Then I again found that just adding   actually disables help page and .asmx?wsdl but it shows service error message which is described [here](http://aspsnippets.com/Articles/Hide-Method-Description-and-Documentation-of-ASP.Net-ASMX-Web-Services-when-browsed.aspx).

Now I want to know does this method has got any disadvantage or problem?

Comment: Yes if it doesn't exist - add it to appropriate place

Comment: @YuriyGalanter But to where it should be added? under which tag?

Answer (score 0):

As I know, we can not completely disable WSDL document. But you can use a Custom WSDL File in ASP.NET Web Services. Which VS version you are using?

Comment: I am using Visual studio 2008